# Returning JsonResult my own object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I got this simple sample in ASP .net core mvc. It responds to jquery's autocomplete, so i get a list of items (as you can see it sends a JSon to the client)

```
public JsonResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    var items = new[] { "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Peach" };

    var filteredItems = items.Where(item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    return Json(filteredItems);//, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

that works well. I return to the client a list of strings. but I want it to send a field of my own object:

---

```
 List<PrvCategory> oCategoriesList;

    //here I load the list with custom code. then....

    var filteredItems = oCategoriesList.Where(item => item.FullName.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    return Json(filteredItems);
```

---

So I got the list of PrvCategory. I want to return a list of strings just like the sample that works, taking one member of it, say:

```
public class PrvCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public String FullName { get; set; }
}
```

so: where before i returned JSon of

```
var items = new[] { "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Peach" };
```

I now want to return the FullName of all the objects in my collection.

I know it must be simple... but I can't find the way to do it. 
Thank You

Comment: `return Json(filteredItems);` looks like it would do the job, although of course the field names returned must match the field names expected by the autocomplete plugin. That might be the missing piece of the jigsaw, although you didn't really make clear what was going wrong. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source shows an example which I think means that you need fields called "label" and "value" in your JSON for it to be able to use them. So you're not far from the solution, I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have a list of all objects from database and want to send only selected properties to view as Json. This can be done using this approach:

```
var filteredItems = items.Where(item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

return Json(filteredItems.Select(x => new
            {
                fullName = x.FullName,              
            }));
```

> The whole function should look like this:

```
public JsonResult Autocomplete(string term){

var items = new[] { "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Peach" };

var filteredItems = items.Where(item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

return Json(filteredItems.Select(x => new
            {
                fullName = x.FullName, 

            })); //, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select a single property of PrvCategory with linq:

```
List<PrvCategory> oCategoriesList;

var filteredItems = oCategoriesList
.Where(item => item.FullName.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
.Select(i => i.FullName);

return Json(filteredItems);
```